# Categorical feature in decision trees in TensorFlow's implementation

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, decision-tree

In Scikit learn's decision tree implementation, I cannot pass nominal data. I will have to either label encode or one hot encode the nominal data. In tensorflow's implementation I can pass the nominal attribute as it is.

How does tensorflow deal with the nominal data under the hood? Does it convert it into one hot or label encoding or does it do something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

Categorical features in Tensorflow are converted to one hot encoding. For more details refer [categorical_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns#categorical_columns)

```
animal_type = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      'Type', ['Cat', 'Dog'])

animal_type_one_hot = feature_column.indicator_column(animal_type)
demo(animal_type_one_hot)
```

Output

```
[[1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]]
```